# ERROR Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 something missed out

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
    CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(25),
    birth_date DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(2),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    branch_id INT 
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-17-11', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);
```

and my problem is:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Noq6.png)

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

why i get this error? something missed out.

Comment: I tested the statements you show, but I did not see the error you show. I suggest you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE employee` and count the columns. You must have more or less than the 8 columns shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Super_id and branch_id don't look nullable. Supply a value or make it nullable.

Also,

With insert statements it's good to explicitly write out columns.

```
Insert into <tablename> (<columnname>, ...) Values (<some value>,...)
```

Comment: Columns are nullable by default unless they have the NOT NULL option (but I did not downvote your answer).

Comment: You're welcome...glad it worked. I'm used to working with different engines and always forget which defaults to what.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your sintax:
Two fields must be nulleable and date must be yyyy-MM-dd

```
   CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(25),
    birth_date DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(2),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT NULL,
    branch_id INT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);
```

See it in action:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de42f

Comment: Columns are nullable by default unless they have the NOT NULL option.

Comment: If you see the sqlfiddle, is working. But you have to correct your time format also.

Answer (score 0):

Your date is wrong.

In MySQL the date formaz has tp be yyyy-mm-dd so 1967-17-11 is not possible

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE employee (
>     emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
>     first_name VARCHAR(40),
>     last_name VARCHAR(25),
>     birth_date DATE,
>     sex VARCHAR(2),
>     salary INT,
>     super_id INT,
>     branch_id INT 
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0a137a6fa557d5f0c38a2141c23d441b)*